# Horizontal Scroll CSS thumbnails

Tags: html, css, ejs

So I have been trying to make a horizontal scroll menu for a bunch of thumbnails.  I have found great info on how to make it scroll horizontally, however my thumbnails still stack on top of eachother and still scroll vertically within my div.  I want all of my thumbnails in one row that scrolls horizontally when there is overflow in the 'x' direction.  I also would like my `div` to stay at a height that is proportional to the width of the thumbnails.  Right now if I do `auto`, the container `div` changes to a height big enough to show all 50 images in multiple rows instead of just one row.  Here is my code

**HTML (.ejs file):**

```
<div class="thumbnail-container">
   <ul class="thumbnail-list">

   <% for (var i = 0; i < listData['photos'].length; i++) { %>
      <li>
         <span><img class="thumbnail-image" src="http://www.realcove.net/<%=listData['photos'][i]%>"></span>
      </li>
   <% } %>
   </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.thumbnail-container {
    overflow-x:scroll;
    height: 75px;
    width:100%;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.thumbnail-list {
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.thumbnail-image {
    display: block;
    padding:2px;
    max-width: 100px;
    height:auto;
}
```

I'm very close, I've done research, and it's just barely not doing what I want it to.  Any thoughts on what I need to fix, or errors I may have??  Your help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your li element still has a display property that makes the elements to stack vertically.

You can change it to display: inline-block;

As for the other question you mentioned. Setting the container height to auto will make the height of the container proportional to the thumbnail. This will work after you set the display property to inline-block;

```
.thumbnail-list li {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

jsfiddle example
https://jsfiddle.net/e99wfqku/1/

Comment: So I am using your exact css code now, and nothing has changed on my end, yet I see that your jsfiddle is doing **exactly** what I want.  Any insight as to why mine still won't work?

Comment: see what is computed rule of the LI element in question in developer tools ? Check if there are any default styles that is preventing it from behaving the way it supposed to.  Check if you have any float's on the LI

Comment: Wow you hit it right on the head, it had a `float: left` on the `li`.  Made it `float: none` and now it works. cheers!